# Trying to get the StoryBoard object that is inside a ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard, key, toast

What I am trying to achieve is to close the window when the Storyboard completes it's job, I tried to set the x:Key attribute in the Storyboard object but I get the following error:
"key attribute can be used only on a tag contained in an IDictionary (such as a ResourceDictionary)"

Here's my code:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyErrorMessage"
                     TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Name="ErrorMessage">
            <Border CornerRadius="4" Width="Auto"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="4,0"
                    Background="#FF404040"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <Label Foreground="White"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Padding="4,2"
                       Margin="4"
                       FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15"
                       Name="Part1"
                       Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Message}" />
            </Border>
            <!-- This TextBlock accepts the content from the parent 'label'. It is not actually displayed, just used to bind data-->
            <TextBlock Name="Part3"
                       Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                       Visibility="Collapsed"></TextBlock>
            <!-- This TextBlock binds to the one above and triggers an animation when it gets updated. -->
            <!-- Its required because TemplateBinding does not allow NotifyOnTargetUpdate -->
            <TextBlock Margin="2"
                       Name="Part2"
                       Foreground="Red"
                       Padding="3"
                       Visibility="Collapsed"
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=Part3, Path=Text,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!-- When Text property of Part2 is blank hide entire control-->
            <Trigger SourceName="Part3"
                     Property="Text"
                     Value="">
                <Setter TargetName="ErrorMessage"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Hidden"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <!-- This trigger is called when Part2 updates which in turn is updated by Part3's databind.
                 It uses animation to make the label fade away after a few seconds.                        -->
            <EventTrigger SourceName="Part2"
                          RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="ErrorMessage" x:Key="gridFadeStoryBoard">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Name="FadeOutAnimation"
                                         Duration="0:0:1.50"
                                         From="1.0"
                                         To="0.0"
                                         BeginTime="0:0:0.50" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Template="{StaticResource MyErrorMessage}" Name="Label1" />
</StackPanel>
```

code-behind:

```
        private Storyboard gridFadeStoryBoard;

    public ToastPopup(string Message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Label1.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();


        gridFadeStoryBoard = this.Label1.Template.Resources["gridFadeStoryBoard"] as Storyboard;
        gridFadeStoryBoard.Completed += new EventHandler(gridFadeStoryBoard_Completed);
    }

    void gridFadeStoryBoard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: There is a big difference between elements in Templates and elements in Resources. A Resource is usually stored in a Dictionary, a ResourceDictionary to be precise. Because its a Dictionary you have a pair of Key and Value, and x:Key is obviously the key for the dictionary. In Templates a key wouldn't make sense but you can name elements in templates with x:Name and use the FindName method. But i'm not sure if this works with storyboards in triggers.

Comment: well have you tried using a Name and in code FindName?